# Add expand-collapse sections to sharepoint survey

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am creating a survey in SharePoint (Office 365). I would like to add expandable-collapsible sections to that survey.
For e.g: My survey will include some 'Basic', 'Application', 'Business specific' questions. I don't want the survey form to look too long. That is why I want to be able to segregate them into expandable-collapsible sections, so that the end user can expand only one section at a time.
How can I add the expandable-collapsible sections?